Started receiving "unable to verify the first certificate" when interacting with the sdk
Versions
What package version of the SDK are you using. (botbuilder@4.16.0)
What nodejs version are you using (v16.20.2)
What os are you using (Mac)
Describe the bug
On July 3rd we started receiving "unable to verify the first certificate" error when starting and using botbuilder sdk APIs. It appears to happen to some but not all customers.
To Reproduce
Instantiate and use any operation botbuilder sdk (send or update message for example)
Expected behavior
No error
"exception":{"message":"unable to verify the first certificate","stack":"Error: unable to verify the first certificate\n    at new RestError (/var/www/app/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/lib/restError.ts:18:5)\n    at AxiosHttpClient. (/var/www/app/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/lib/axiosHttpClient.ts:194:15)\n    at step (/var/www/app/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)\n    at Object.throw (/var/www/app/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)\n    at rejected (/var/www/app/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:69)\n    at runMicrotasks ()\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"},"level":"error","message":"Failure updating message: unable to verify the first certificate"
We restarted our service, we are expecting no errors to be returned
GH Issue: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/4708
